# How to change the android emulator RAM size from the command line?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to edit or change the ram size while creating the android emulator from command line.

EX: While creating the emulator it's taking default ram size(Android SDK 4.0.3) 512 MB
But I want to increase it to 768MB or decrease it to 256MB.

I want to change only Ram size. Because there is an option to change the Ram size.

```
 Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no] Yes
```

If you entered yes, we need to provide so many things.

Answer (score 20):

You need to find the config file for the AVD that you have created.

In my case, I'm running the AVD on Ubuntu, so this is where I found the config file.

```
~/.android/avd/emulator.avd/config.ini
```

"emulator" was the name I provided when I created the AVD, so the directory name will depend on what you provided.

The following is what is inside the config.ini file:

```
hw.lcd.density=240
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi
vm.heapSize=64
hw.ramSize=1024
image.sysdir.1=platforms/android-8/images/
```

I increased my heap size from 24 to 64, and added the ram size parameter.

For the list of parameters you can add, refer to: [Managing AVDs from the Command-line](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018030620/http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html)

Comment: the new working link is http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html but several parameters are not listed: vm.heapSize, disk.dataPartition.size, hw.lcd.height, hw.lcd.width...

Answer (score 14):

To answer the question in the title,

> how to change the android emulator ram size from command line?

one has to use `-memory` option:

```
emulator -memory 768 -avd <AVD_NAME>
```

or

```
emulator -memory 256 -avd <AVD_NAME>
```

Comment: Reference document for emulator flag options: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options

Comment: And that's not changing configuration, but just launching emulator with specified amount of memory. `config.ini` still remains the same.

Comment: @eleven: well, if we are going that technical, then `-memory` option does indeed change the emulator RAM size. It just does not persist the change (or save it to config file).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default value of `hw.ramSize` in `hardware.ini` which you uses. For example, if you change the `platforms/android-15/skins/**WVGA800**/hardware.ini` to

```
hw.lcd.density=240
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=1024
```

Then you can create an avd that has 1024M of ram by using:

```
android create avd -f -t <target> -s **WVGA800** -n test_avd
```

Comment: Using WVGA800 did not work for me — but then I create an API 10 compatibility tests emulator.