# How to reduce the memory used by the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way to reduce memory used by android emulator? When I turn on Resource Monitor, It commits over 800MB(I guess this is the reason for all my computer's lags)!

My info:

OS: 
Window 7, 2GB RAM, CPU core i3.

Emulator:
Device RAM size: 512MB, data partition size: 384MB, Skin: HVGA 480x320, SD Card: 4GiB.

Comment: when you create a new Android virtual device you can change the amount of ram you want to use.

Comment: CLI only version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-ram-size-from-command-line

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Open the Android Virtual device manager:

[image]

Click on a device and select edit:

[image]

and then on Hardware click new:

[image]

After that select the option Device ram size:

[image]

Then just put the value that you want and click on Edit AVD:

[image]

Hope that helps.  Also as you may notice you can change other properties that might be useful.

Comment: Probably that is the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to reduce the Device RAM to maybe 384 MB or 256 MB, as long as you keep the VM RAM size the same it should not affect how your app run in the emulator (except maybe making the emulator run even slower)

But if you want to do software development, 4GB RAM should be the minimum, RAMs are very cheap right now and you really should sharper your tools anyway.

Comment: I think over 800MB RAM is too expensive for me:D. 384MB-> 800MB, 128MB-> runs into INSTALL_FAIL_APK error. Hmm.

Comment: I really think you should just get another 2GB RAM and this problem would be solved, and your computer would run slightly faster with everything. ;)