# How can I reduce Android Emulator resource consumption?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have tried looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533818/how-to-reduce-the-memory-used-by-the-android-emulator) but I already have 16GB of RAM and I don't want to decrease AVD memory. I do not understand why the Android Emulator takes up so many resources (%25+ CPU, Almost 1GB of RAM) when running a simple app (Like this: Single Activity with a RecyclerView and its Adapter. That's it). Any help would be appreciated.

My fan is always on when using the Android Emulator in Android Studio.

[image: CPU usage]

[image: Memory usage]

Comment: I don't have a solid answer, but potentially trying [one of these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063267/high-cpu-usage-with-android-emulator-qemu-system-i386-exe?rq=1) might work.

Comment: Very minimal change. %25 CPU -> ~%23 CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal for the Android Emulator. My numbers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big pain for me and even bigger after upgrading the AndroidStudio version.

**One alternative is to use an external Device for Debugging in place of an Emulator.**