# Android Emulator is Very Slow in 8GB Ram in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want Run Android Emulator in Windows 10 .I have 8GB ram.When I Create Android Emulator than run when my Laptop is Very Hot and Create More Hot Air.Please Help me .I don't have any Smart-Phone.Please Help me. Thank you

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533818/how-to-reduce-the-memory-used-by-the-android-emulator) that explains how to limit the ram usage, you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to use an Android emulator on my old PC. The solution that worked for me was to use something like BlueStacks to run my android application after exporting my project as an apk. The emulator that I configured with Android studio used to crash my PC as well, so hope that this works for you !