# Android/Java Out of memory on a -byte allocation with cipher.getOutputSize() "OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: android, arrays, out-of-memory, aes, bouncycastle

I have a problem with a function of Decrypt in Aes with Bouncy castle.

I have a regular function to encrypt/decrypt, but is too slow. Now I am trying to fix this problem using a part of code of an example of the test file in the BouncyCastle' Lib. I write a code like this:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SymmetricencryptionexamplewithpaddingandCBCusingDESwiththeinitializationvectorinline.htm

Now I receive an error

> "E/dalvikvm-heap(548): Out of memory on a 52023154-byte allocation."
>
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when try to allocate byte[] plainText.

I have no problem with file of size 1-2 MB, but on a file larger than 2MB is there this error.

I don't have any idea for this and haven't find any response on web. Can you help me?

Comment: I have modified my question with the solution but i don't know how accept it

Comment: You can copy the text to the answer field, notice that you can post answers to your own questions and accept them (it should be in the FAQ I think). You just cannot gain reputation from the accept.

Comment: yes, but some times ago i can't share an answer, my answer became a comment. now it's ok! thanks bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution in this post:
[How to change the android emulator RAM size from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-ram-size-from-command-line) 
With this upgrade my heap size! thanks to the comunity!