# AVD crashing directly after Android screen

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device

I'm attempting to work with Phonegap/Cordova, following this tutorial: http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

However, when I attempt to run the AVD I have set up, it runs, gets to the Android screen on the emulator, and then immediately shuts down with no fanfare.

The command line then says:

```
Error executing "adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim": error: device not found.
```

I've been Googling for about a day already, and I can't find anyone else running into this. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with my environment and me doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it would be.

Comment: I found this answer on stackoverflow


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-ram-size-from-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - I hadn't allocated enough RAM to the AVD. Bumping it up from 500mb to 768mb fixed my problem.