# Can we set emulator RAM size via console before we start emulator?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, console, adb

My emulators usually use 512MB or 1GB of RAM. I create a shell script which starts 8 emulators for my testing. Obviously, it will consume all of my available RAM.

Is there a way I tell emulator to use less RAM via console command? Some ad hoc RAM size which will not change the default RAM size.

I usually start emulators via (Ubuntu  machine)

```
 emulator -avd "adb name" -scale 0.72
```

Comment: For reference, a similar question was already asked (albeit with no proper answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we set emulator RAM size via console before we start emulator?

Yes, please use `-memory` option; e.g.:

```
emulator -memory 256 -avd Nexus_One_API_10 -scale 0.72
```

Comment: How can I test if the device actually used 256RAM? I see memory resources consume more than 256MB RAM. Even more it consumes the same memory with or without this switch.

Comment: `#cat /proc/meminfo` from emulator's adb shell. The actual host memory used by the emulator overall may also depend on other things than the RAM size.

Comment: Hm, so decreasing RAM does not help me to run 8 emulators in the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can set the RAM through [emulator command line parameters](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options), but if you are starting your emulators with a script you can edit the emulator `config.ini` file before starting it.

On Ubuntu, the file should be located at `~/.android/avd/emulator.avd/config.ini`. Before starting each emulator, open the corresponding `config.ini` file, set `hw.ramSize` to the desired value, save the change, and then launch your emulator with the new settings. A bit tedious, but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: I tried to avoid editing cinfig.ini for each emulator. I am doing it right now. That is why I asked if there is a command-line parameter