# Error in starting emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I got this error when start emulator please help me i tried many solutions. Updated graphics drivers, ram changes and screen resolution is 1280*1024.

Logcat error:

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: device fd:512
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
ERROR: Could not create window texture: Texture dimensions are limited to 2048x2048
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main problem is related to the emulator memory,so please take a look at below link
[How to change the android emulator RAM size from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-ram-size-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i tried with avd editor to change settings. Is there difference with command line or necessary?

Comment: There is not any difference.however try to use administrator permission when you do any changes

Comment: Thanks again brother for you time. I solve this issue by changing screen resolution. Simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution change your screen resolution sometime it effect the emulator and emulator stop working.